# Create Azure website with Standard pricing tier via Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I'm trying to fix my continious deployment scenario and for this to work an Azure website has to exist and be able to swap between the Staging and Production. We want this website to work in the `Standard` pricing tier.

The script I have at the moment creates a new ResourceGroup, Hosting Plan and after these are created, the website itself. The problem I'm facing is the website is always in `Free` mode. I should be able to fix this by using the `Set-AzureResource` cmdlet, but this one is throwing an message telling me I should specify the `Location`. Problem with this is this specific cmdlet doesn't has a `Location` parameter.

> ```
> Set-AzureResource : {
>   "Error": {
>     "Code": "LocationRequired",
>     "Message": "The location property is required for this definition.",
>     "Target": null,
>     "Details": null
>   }
> }
> ```

This is the (simplified) script I'm using to create all of the resources:

```
#Create the resource group
New-AzureResourceGroup -Location $location -Name $resourceGroupName -Force

#Create the hosting plan
$hostingPlanParameters = @{"name" = $hostingPlanName; "sku" = "Standard"; "computeMode" = "Standard"; "workerSize" = "0"; "numberOfWorkers" = "1"}

New-AzureResource -ApiVersion 2014-04-01 -Name $hostingPlanName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
                            -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/serverFarms -Location $location `
                            -PropertyObject $hostingPlanParameters -Verbose -Force
#Create the website
$analyticsSite = @{"sku" = "Standard"; "webHostingPlan" = $hostingplan; "computeMode" = "Standard"; }
New-AzureResource  -Name $label -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites `
                             -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location `
                             -ApiVersion $apiVersion -PropertyObject $analyticsSite -Force

Set-AzureResource -Name $label -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites `
                             -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ApiVersion $apiVersion `
                             -PropertyObject $analyticsSite -Force
```

I've read the website should inherit the `sku` of the specified hosting plan, so I should not need to update it. This does not appear to work for my above script. The hosting plan is specified, but the settings aren't inheritted.

The created hosting plan properties look like this:

```
PropertiesText    : {
                      "name": "devHostingPlanWestEU10",
                      "sku": "Standard",
                      "workerSize": 0,
                      "workerSizeId": 0,
                      "numberOfWorkers": 1,
                      "currentWorkerSize": 0,
                      "currentWorkerSizeId": 0,
                      "currentNumberOfWorkers": 1,
                      "status": 0,
                      "webSpace": "ResourceGroupWestEU10-WestEuropewebspace",
                      "subscription": "ad7add9b-8b7a-45df-8e95-0e7fccbr78a5",
                      "adminSiteName": null,
                      "hostingEnvironment": null,
                      "maximumNumberOfWorkers": 0,
                      "planName": null,
                      "perSiteScaling": null,
                      "hostingEnvironmentId": null
                    }
```

This looks kind of ok to me.
Once the website is created, these properties are printed:

```
PropertiesText    : {
                      "name": "Testert10",
                      "state": "Running",
                      "hostNames": [
                        "testert10.azurewebsites.net"
                      ],
                      "webSpace": "ResourceGroupWestEU10-WestEuropewebspace",
                      ...
                      "repositorySiteName": "Testert10",
                      "owner": null,
                      "usageState": 0,
                      "enabled": true,
                      ...
                      "computeMode": null,
                      "serverFarm": "Default1",
                      "serverFarmId": null,
                      "lastModifiedTimeUtc": "2015-05-21T11:52:30.773",
                      "storageRecoveryDefaultState": "Running",
                      "contentAvailabilityState": 0,
                      "runtimeAvailabilityState": 0,
                      "siteConfig": null,
                      "deploymentId": "Testert10",
                      "trafficManagerHostNames": null,
                      "sku": "Free",
                      "premiumAppDeployed": null,
                      "scmSiteAlsoStopped": false,
                      "targetSwapSlot": null,
                      "hostingEnvironment": null,
                      "microService": "WebSites",
                      "gatewaySiteName": null,
                      "kind": null,
                      "cloningInfo": null,
                      "hostingEnvironmentId": null
                    }
```

As you can see, the computeMode, serverFarm, hostingEnvironment and sku aren't set with the properties I set in the `$analyticsSite` object.

Therefore I probably need to update the resource, but this throws the error mentioned above.

I've also tried using the `New-AzureWebsite`, using [Troy Hunt's blogpost](http://www.troyhunt.com/2015/01/automating-web-hosting-creation-in.html) as an example. However, this post also relies on using the `Set-AzureResource`, so I'll fall into the same problem. A different problem with this example is you can't control on which resource group and hosting plan the site is created which will cause a bit of trouble when searching for the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible so easily in the new RM cmdlets. Make sure that you have the latest version of Azure PowerShell first.

First create an App service plan that defines the Standard Price tier, then create a web app with the app service plan.

```html
function Create-AppServicePlan()
{
    #https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt619306.aspx
    $resource = Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceNameContains $ServicePlanName -ResourceGroupNameContains $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/ServerFarms"
    if(!$resource)
    {
        # Specify the Tier type that you would like
        $servicePlan = New-AzureRmAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $ServicePlanName -Location $WebAppLocation -Tier Standard -NumberofWorkers 1 -WorkerSize "Small"
    }
}
```

Next create the web app with the app service plan as a parameter.

```html
function Create-AzureRmWebApp()
{
    #https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt619250.aspx
    $resource = Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceNameContains $WebAppName -ResourceGroupNameContains $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites"
    if(!$resource)
    {
        $webApp = New-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $WebAppName -Location $WebAppLocation -AppServicePlan $ServicePlanName
    }
}
```

This is the full working script that is verified working.

```html
$ServicePlanName = "PSScriptAppServicePlann"
$WebAppName = "WebAppByPSlooksCool"
$ResourceGroupName = "MyResourceGroup"
$WebAppLocation = "australiaeast"
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

# Step 1: Create the application service plan
Create-AppServicePlan

# Step 2: Create the web app using the service plan name.
Create-AzureRmWebApp

function Create-AzureRmWebApp()
{
    #https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt619250.aspx
    $resource = Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceNameContains $WebAppName -ResourceGroupNameContains $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites"
    if(!$resource)
    {
        $webApp = New-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $WebAppName -Location $WebAppLocation -AppServicePlan $ServicePlanName
    }
}

function Create-AppServicePlan()
{
    #https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt619306.aspx
    $resource = Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceNameContains $ServicePlanName -ResourceGroupNameContains $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/ServerFarms"
    if(!$resource)
    {
        # Specify the Tier type that you would like
        $servicePlan = New-AzureRmAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $ServicePlanName -Location $WebAppLocation -Tier Standard -NumberofWorkers 1 -WorkerSize "Small"
    }
}
```

Comment: obvious follow up question - now how does one deploy an actual website (from directory) into this AzureRmWebApp?

Comment: @taras.roshko Do you mean from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you created your site in a default free App Service Plan (aka Server Farm or Web Hosting Plan - they're all the same thing), called "Default1".  Yet the App Service Plan you scaled to the Standard size was a different one called "devHostingPlanWestEU10".

To create a site in a pre-existing App Service Plan use the following command:

(split into multiple lines for readability)

```
New-AzureResource 
  -Name <YourSiteName>
  -Location "West US" 
  -ResourceGroupName  <YourResourceGroupName> 
  -ApiVersion 2014-11-01 
  -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites" 
  -PropertyObject @{ "serverFarm" = "<Your service plan name>" }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've indeed tried adding the `serverFarm` property, using `$analyticsSite = @{"name" = $label; "sku" = "Standard"; "webHostingPlan" = $hostingplan; "serverFarm" = $hostingplan}`, but it throws an error telling me the specified `serverFarm` does not exists. In Troy Hunt's post both the hosting plan and serverfarm are the same as well, like you are suggesting also. Is there something I'm doing wrong while creating the hosting plan? Can't seem to figure out what it is though...

Comment: Can you share the exact command you're running (with all the variables inlined)? Take out webHostingPlan, replace the $hostingPlan variable with it's string content.  That'll make this easier to debug

Answer (score 0):

With the New Azure Resource Manager Cmdlet. You can create a new **App Service Plan and Pass it to the New-AzureRmWebApp Cmdlet.**

*New-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name **StdPlan** -Location <"Location"> -ResourceGroupName <"ResourceGroupName"> -**Tier Standard***

*New-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName <"ResourceGroupName"> -Name <"WebAppname"> -Location <"Location"> -AppServicePlan **StdPlan***

Reference Article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-app-azure-resource-manager-powershell